# Can I create and handle a pygame sprite not in a group the same way as if it's in a group?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm coding an arkanoid game.
Blocks are defined as sprites and grouped in a sprite group.

I'd like to define ball as a sprite too but since it's a single object use it as an item and not as part of a "ball" group.

The problem is that when I code it like this :

```
class ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((BALL, BALL))
        self.image.fill((255,0,255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = pos[0]
        self.rect.centery = pos[1]


ball_item = ball((5,5))
```

I'm unable to use sprite group methods such as `ball_item.draw()`

Is there a way to overcome this?

P.s. I can group ball into ball_group and use `ball_group.sprites()[0]` to address it, but seems cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a separate [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group%60) and just put the ball object in the group:

```py
ball_group = pygame.sprite.Group([ball((5,5))])
```

Furthermore, there is the is [`pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.GroupSingle), which is a Group container that holds a single sprite:

```py
ball_group = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle(ball((5,5)))
```

Note, you can get the [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) object which is in a *Group* by the method [`sprites()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.sprites) and subscription:

```py
ball_item = ball_group.sprites()[0]
```

Comment: Thanks but even if I'm defining it as pygame.sprite.GroupSingle(), I'm still unable to change a property in ball_group Like this:
ball_group.x =5

I have to go through : ball_item = ball_group.sprites()[0]
and then ball_item.x = 5

I'm looking for a way to do this without using 
ball_group.sprites()[0]

Comment: I see, so it seems there's no way around grouping. 
Too bad.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Niv There is no way to do that. You need the Group and the Sprite. Alternatively you've to implement your own `draw` method in the Sprite class.